# HTML5 Video Playback - image preload

Tags: html, video, image-preloader

I am using video tags and jQuery to display a HTML5 video playback.

How can I show an image while the video is still loading for displaying?

I would use jQuery for this..

Thanks in advance!

PD: Display an image when the video preloads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for JQuery to achieve this as the html5 video tag comes with its own poster attribute. You can use that to specify what image should be displayed while the video loads. For instance if you have an image called `myImage.jpg` you can do the following: `<video controls="controls" poster="myImage.jpg">`. Refer here for more info:

https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video#HTML_Attributes

Comment: @JamesKyle, regardless of all the issues w3schools might have it is still a useful site.

Comment: there are much better sites out there

Comment: I would like a preload animation image when the video is not still available